# Session doesn't remember set value

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I am trying to pass data between two pages using Session State in ASP.NET. The data that needs to be passed is from a GridView's Cell. So, on SelectedIndexChanged event I'm storing the data like that:

```
protected void GridViewEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Session["Name"] =   
           this.GridViewEmployees.Rows[GridViewEmployees.SelectedIndex].DataItem;
}
```

And then, I want to use the Session's contents in another page. The code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string name = (string)(Session["Name"]);
        string[] names = name.Split(' ');
        this.EntityDataSourceNorthwind.Where = 
           "it.[FirstName] = \'" + names[0] + 
           "\' AND it.[lastName] = \'" + names[1] + "\'";
}
```

But I get a null reference exception. Also, I have set the Session initialization on the Page_Load event and there the Session is stored and everything works just fine. I mean:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Session["Name"] == null)
        {
            Session["Name"] = "Andrew Fuller";
        }
}
```

This is in the page which sends the information.

If you need more source or info, just write it down. It will be provided ASAP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the GridViewEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged method every being called correctly?

Comment: Put a `if( ! Page.IsPostBack ){ if(Session ... }`  into your `Page_Load` and see if that helps.

Comment: @skaz I have tried to get the data via several ways but it's not happening via any... @rlb.usa didn't helped but it was sth that is needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not a problem with your Session.  A row's DataItem is only available during the RowDataBound event.  Set a break point in your  GridViewEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged method, and check the value of the DataItem in your immediate window.  It will be null.

Answer (score 1):

The two most likely culprits are either - session state is disabled (`EnableSessionState="false"`), or cookies are disabled and you're not using [cookieless sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx).